# How to add more then one text to an animation. (Reactjs, CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs

I created a simple react js page that have one text in it and I created an animation for it in a css file. the text will fade in and out. now I want to add more text to that animation where the first text disapper (reach 0 opacity) the second text will start his animation in the same place. I want the animation to not reapet it self, meaning when the second text dissapear another text will fade in but not out and it will stays. I am very new to reactjs and css so I have no idea how can I do it. Can someone please help figur out how to do it? Thank you for taking the time to read the question

**This is my react js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Intro.css'

function Intro() {
  return (
    <div className='text-container'>
      <text className='animated-text'>
        Some text
      </text>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Intro
```

**And this is my css file:**

```
.text-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.animated-text {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: Rochester;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding-bottom: 10vh;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    animation: fadeInOut 10s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    11.11% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    33.33% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    44.44% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```